# Scanning wifi on newer versions of android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wifimanager

I'm writing a Work Tracker application, which needs to scan the nearby wifi hotspots for security.
I'm trying to follow the code given at [Google's official site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan), but it keeps failing. I read somewhere that this code won't work on newer versions of android, and well enough it doesn't work neither on the Android 12 emulator, nor on my Android 10 device. How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
fun checkWifiChannels(
    localContext: Context
) {
    val wifiManager = localContext.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
            if(success) {
                scanSuccess(wifiManager, localContext)
            } else {
                scanFailure(wifiManager, localContext)
            }
        }
    }

    val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
    localContext.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter)

    val success = wifiManager.startScan()
    if(!success) {
        scanFailure(wifiManager, localContext)
    }
}

private fun scanSuccess(
    wifiManager: WifiManager,
    localContext: Context
) {
    val results = wifiManager.scanResults
    Toast.makeText(localContext, "Scan successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    println(results.toString())
}

private fun scanFailure(
    wifiManager: WifiManager,
    localContext: Context
) {
    val results = wifiManager.scanResults
    println("Scan not successful, old results:")
    Toast.makeText(localContext, "Scan not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    println(results.toString())
}
```

Here's the `localContext` variable declared in a `@Composable` function:

```
val localContext = LocalContext.current
```

This code always prints "Scan not successful", and I can't find anything online how am I supposed to solve this, I'm pretty new to android programming.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess "newer" means Android 9 in this context.

Comment: " but it keeps failing", could you elaborate what does that mean? the app crashes, you maybe get some strange log statements or nothing happens at all?

Comment: By failing I meant the app doesn't crash, but it simply won't scan for wifi. It always returns "Scan not successful" with an empty list.